# Comparing method in Comparator Interface

Tags: java, comparator, functional-interface

I wanted to explicitly implement "apply" method from Function interface. I have the following code, how can I provide implementation for "apply" method using anonymous class. just wanted to know what is going on in the background.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[][] doubles = {{5.0, 4.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {4.0, 6.0}};

    Function<double[],Double> keyExtractor = a->a[0];
    Comparator<double[]>comparator = Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor);

    Arrays.sort(doubles,comparator);

    for(double[] val: doubles)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(val));

}
```

Comment: Look up what the significance of a "single abstract method" is.

Comment: a -> a[0] is the implementation for apply method.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of `apply` method using anonymous class:

```
    Function<double[], Double> keyExtractor = new Function<double[], Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double apply(double[] t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return t[0];
            }
        };
```